# weak derivative of complex absolute value function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-derivatives

I would like if is possible to calculate the weak derivative of the complex absolute value function, i.e., $ f: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+},$ where $f(z) = |z|^{2}, z\in \mathbb{C}$, by solving $$\int_{\mathbb{C}} fg' d\mu =-\int_{\mathbb{C}} vg d\mu, $$ where $v$ is the weak derivative of $f$ and the function $g$ is infinitely differentiable with compact support, i.e., $g\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{C})$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by $g'$ ? $g$ is not necessarily complex differentiable. Maybe you mean a [Wirtinger derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives) $\partial_z$? Also, what is $\mu$? Lebesgue measure? Also note that your $f$ is smooth as a function of two real variables.

Comment: thank for your comment. Well, g' represents the first derivative of function g and g is defined in the complex space also. Moreover,  μ represent the Lebesgue measure but I want the weak derivative in the complex domain if is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you really do mean the complex derivative, compact supported smooth(i.e. entire) functions   $g∈ C^∞_0(\mathbb C)$ are constant; compact support forces this constant to be 0 so any $v$ will do. When playing with complex derivatives we don't have bump functions or anything that comes with it, e.g. weak derivatives or partitions of unity.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Note that when z takes only real values the weak derivative is the same as in the real case and when z has only complex values. The problem is when z has both.

Comment: @SamuelEduardoPinillaSanchez nope! By forcing the use of the complex derivatives, you reduce the set of testing functions to the zero function. If you are actually asking for $C^∞_0(\mathbb R ; \Bbb C)$ functions then $g'$ is a *real* derivative, not complex, and you will obtain the answer by writing everything in terms of $\Bbb R^2$ valued functions instead of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @SamuelEduardoPinillaSanchez Hopefully you are aware of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)

Comment: thank you man, you are alright!.